# conntrack delete does not stop runnig copy of big file

Tags: c, linux, kernel, nat, netfilter

I have a router with nat port forwarding configured. I launched a http copy of big file via the nat. The http server is hosted on the LAN PC which contains the big file to download. I launched the file download from WAN PC.
I disabled the nat rule when file copy is running. the copy of file keep remaining. I want to stop the copy of file when I disable the nat forward rule with conntrack-tool.

[image]

my conntrack list contains the following conntrack session

```
# conntrack -L | grep "33.13"
tcp      6 431988 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.33.13 dst=192.168.33.215 sport=52722 dport=80 src=192.168.3.17 dst=192.168.33.13 sport=80 dport=52722 [ASSURED] use=1
```

I tried to remove it with the following command:

```
# conntrack -D --orig-src 192.168.33.13
tcp      6 431982 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.33.13 dst=192.168.33.215 sport=52722 dport=80 src=192.168.3.17 dst=192.168.33.13 sport=80 dport=52722 [ASSURED] use=1
conntrack v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): 1 flow entries have been deleted.
```

the conntrack session is removed I can see in the following command. But another conntrack session was created with src ip address is the lan address of the removed conntrack

```
# conntrack -L | grep "33.13"
tcp      6 431993 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.3.17 dst=192.168.33.13 sport=80 dport=52722 src=192.168.33.13 dst=192.168.33.215 sport=52722 dport=80 [ASSURED] use=1
conntrack v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): 57 flow entries have been shown.
```

I tried to remove the new conntrack but it keep remaining

```
# conntrack -D --orig-src 192.168.3.17

# conntrack -L | grep "33.13"
conntrack v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): 11 flow entries have been shown.
tcp      6 431981 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.3.17 dst=192.168.33.13 sport=80 dport=52722 src=192.168.33.13 dst=192.168.33.215 sport=52722 dport=80 [ASSURED] use=1
```

What I m missing?

Comment: I the C tag relevant?

Comment: It's a long time since I looked at iptables, but I think your iptable rules in the router is highly relevant to be able to have a clue what is going on

Answer (score 0):

first, if "conntrack -D" command succeed, you can see below Messsage.

> conntrack v1.4.4 (conntrack-tools): 1 flow entries have been deleted.

So we guess that track deleltion working was failed.

Why do not conntrack delete track?

> Perhaps you are referencing a session you want to delete from a specific skb or track.

if you want to get detail infomation, you try to follow "ctnetlink_del_conntrack " call stack  funcion in linux kernel.